# PayPal Sandbox IPN URL returns "Secure Connection Failed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Some time ago I set up a page on my in-progress web site for purchase processing with PayPay using IPN and a Sandbox account.

Everything was working fine, mock payments were completing successfully, but it's been a couple of months since I last tested this part of the site, and I've suddenly found that it's no longer functioning.

Nothing has changed with the page, but I'm getting an "Internal Server Error" response when my page redirects to the "Sandbox URL":
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

I frequently find myself going around in circles with the PayPal documentation, there often appear to be two or more entirely separate documents describing the same procedure, and with conflicting information.

For example, this page describes the IPN testing process as I've been following it to date: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside

- it is the URL provided by this page that is now returning the 500 Internal Server Error message. But I've subsequently discovered this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/#sandbox
- which indicates an entirely different Sandbox URL. The latter looks more up-to-date, but changing my URL to redirect here results in a "Secure Connection Failed" message in FireFox (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome).

Are both of these URLs invalid? Is the Sandbox site presently not processing payments? The situation is very confusing and I can't figure out what might be wrong.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a PayPal encrypted button for IPN and I get the same 500 "Internal Server Error" in the Sandbox that you are getting on the checkout page.  I did not change my code either and I'm suddenly getting this error on PayPal's sandbox.

Unfortunately, PayPal is putting a low priority on fixing this.  If you want the Sandbox to be fixed, open a ticket with them.  The only way they will address this if enough customers complain.

Comment: As with DzoniT, I can't think you enough for letting my know that this is a wider problem, and not limited to my own set-up. I appreciate your suggestion about opening a ticket too, I'll do that next.

Comment: No problem.  I opened up a ticket with them last week but they still haven't fixed the problem.  I think we need more people to open a ticket with them before they take this seriously and fix it.  Otherwise, they may sit on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that sandbox is down, I have same problem with my website currently.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming this, it's really reassuring - though frustrating for us all - to know that I'm not alone in having the problem.

Comment: @dzonit, please join us in opening a support ticket. If enough customers complain, PayPal may fix the problem.  They haven't fixed this for over a week and without more customer complaints, I'm not sure they will move any further.

Comment: @ProgrammerJoe already did, let's hope they will solve it soon